# How can I access original observable value in tap after map?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am building an Angular 6 guard. After the boolean is calculated by the `map` operator, I would like the original value of user available in the `tap` operator to calculate the redirect.

```
return this.auth.user$.pipe(
    take(1),
    // Existing Users cannot register
    map(user => user ? false : true),
    tap(canAccess => {
        if (!canAccess) {
            // Calculate route based on user value
        }
    })
);
```

I am very new to RxJS. Is there a way to access the original user value in the `tap` operator without creating a duplicate user observable?

(I guess I could technically `tap` before the `map`, but it seems odd to redirect before transforming the value.)

Comment: Just swap them; do your tap first and then your map.

Comment: Well technically, I'm using the result of `map` (canAccess) in the `tap` code. If I `tap` first, I would have to duplicate the logic in `map`.

Comment: Then you do not really need tap at all and you can just put your logic in the map only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map`, `tap` and then `map` again. The last `map` allows you to end up with an `Observable<boolean>`, which I suppose you require in the end.

- `map(user => [user, !user])` maps the original value to an array of two values: the user and their access flag (boolean)
- `tap([user, canAccess]) => { ... }` takes both values and does the computations you need on the user depending on the flag
- `map(([user, canAccess]) => canAccess)` takes both values and return the one you need in the end (the boolean flag)

This way you don't have to duplicate your `canAccess` condition.

```
return this.auth.user$.pipe(
  take(1),
  map(user => [user, !user]),   // !user should be equivalent to user ? false : true
  tap(([user, canAccess]) => {
    if (!canAccess) {
      // Calculate route based on user value
    }
  }),
  map(([user, canAccess]) => canAccess)
);
```

Comment: ...Ah, I see what you did there ;)

Comment: @Lidauson I'll add explanations to my answer in a minute.

Comment: I understand. You transformed the value supplied to `map` to an array which includes the original user value.

Comment: Shouldn't that last `map` have a comma instead of a period prefix?

Comment: @Lindauson Added some explaining text anyway :) and yes, you're absolutely right about that last `map`! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Doing what you're doing right now will transform the `user` to a `boolean`. So in that next `tap`, you'll eventually get a `boolean`.

Why don't you use the `user` directly in the `tap` and get rid of that `map`?

If `user` is defined, `if(!user)` will resolve to `false` anyway.

And if `user` is `undefined` or `null`, then `if(!user)` will resolve to `true`.

And yeah, as you said, since you need to return an `Observable<boolean>`, you'll have to `map` it to a `boolean`

So you can use this:

```
return this.auth.user$.pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(user => {
        if (!user) {
            // Calculate route based on user value
        }
    }),
    map(user => user ? false : true)
);
```

Comment: canActivate requires I return a boolean, so I would still have to map. But I guess what you're saying is what I thought originally: `tap` before `map`.

Comment: @Lindauson, makes sense. Updated the answer.